# Changing size and pose of the geometry of a Gazebo entity from a gz-sim system plugin

Tags: gazebo, gz-sim

Is it possible to change the size and position of the geometry (box shape) of a collision entity and a visual entity, at runtime from a Gazebo sim system plugin?

What I intend to try is the following:

- Retrieve the [geometry component](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/579013fe2841de68c0901192780ab8ee86cc9bb1/include/gz/sim/components/Geometry.hh#L45-L46) and [pose](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/579013fe2841de68c0901192780ab8ee86cc9bb1/include/gz/sim/components/Pose.hh#L35) components of the entity,
- Change these, and
- Hope it has an effect :-)

But it would be great to get some feedback first, as I don't fully understand the interaction between `gz-sim`, `gz-gui` and `gz-physics`, so I can't assess if this will work (and I rather assume not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gz-sim currently does not handle requests to change geometry properties like size. You can however move models by setting the `WorldPoseCmd` component but not collisions. You maybe able to change the pose of visuals by setting the entity's `Pose` component. For geometry size changes, one workaround (not ideal) would be to delete and spawn a new model.

Comment: I did not get around to implementing this yet, but think I will indeed resort to moving visuals and collisions instead of resizing them, either by defining those in separate models and using `WorldPoseCmd`, or by adding them to links of one model and using the `JointPositionController` system.